# Canvas GUI Toolkit

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, desktop

Is there a simple (and fast) toolkit for drawing things on a canvas (e.g. circles, lines, rectangles)?

It would be best if it was in Python, Java, C++.

I'm trying to make an application that drag'n'drops items to a canvas and moving them around in the canvas.

I've looked at a few, pyglet, Java Swing, HTML5 or are there other ones more suitable?

Comment: `more suitable` ? in what way are those not sutable? and do you want to embed it in a browser or not?

Comment: I'd prefer a desktop application, but web apps is ok too

Comment: From what I hear about pyglet it will be the easiest to accomplish your Desktop drag&drop media-displaying canvas. (btw.: web apps? That would be the 3rd category you mention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Qt's(C++ toolkit, there are also Python bindings - PyQt & PySide) [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/graphicsview.html).
And here are some [examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/examples-graphicsview.html).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If considering HTML5 Canvas, I would take a look at [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/).